# Copy / paste same range of cells of many sheets from one book to another

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I'm rather new to VBA and I'm trying hard to solve the following problem. I usually get an excel file with 10-20 sheets. Then, I copy the same range of cells (i76:i133) of every sheet from one book to another book that has the same sheet structure.

I'm trying to make a loop to code this easily but I'm failing.

```
Sub copy()

Dim Sourcebook As Workbook
Dim Destinationbook As Workbook, mysheet As Worksheet

Set Sourcebook = Workbooks("Quarterly.xlsx")
Set Destinationbook = Workbooks("Master.xlsx")

For Each mysheet In Sourcebook.Worksheets
    Sourcebook.Sheets(mysheet).Range("I76:I133").Copy
    Destinationbook.Sheets(mysheet).Range("I76").Paste
Next

End Sub
```

I get a

> run-time error 13, type mismatch

in `Sourcebook.Sheets(mysheet).Range("I76:I133").Copy`

Any help would be very welcome!

Comment: Are both workbooks already opened? Otherwise you will have a problem.

Answer (score 3):

Your `mySheet` variable is of `Worksheet type` while you are trying to use it as a `String`. Here is your loop improved:

```
For Each mysheet In Sourcebook.Worksheets

    'Sourcebook.Sheets(mysheet).Range("I76:I133").Copy 'instead of this...
    mysheet.Range("I76:I133").Copy '...use this

    Destinationbook.Sheets(mysheet.Name).Range("I76").Paste

Next
```

Comment: `Destinationbook.Sheets(mysheet)` ? don't you mean `Destinationbook.Sheets(mysheet.Name)` ? You need to have a `String` inside the brackets (or index)

Comment: @ShaiRado But this is still cleaner. Although `mysheet.name` would've nailed it too.